# Process.all(array.map(... doesn't work in parallel with page.goto(

Tags: promise, puppeteer, array.prototype.map

I am using the pupperteer library for my bot and I would like to perform some operations in parallel.
In many articles, it is advised to use this syntax  :

```
await Promise.all(array.map(async data => //..some operations))
```

I've tested this on several operations and it works but when I embed the code below in my .map promise

```
await page.goto(..
```

It did not work during Operation Promise and it considers this to be a synchronous operation.
I would like to know why it reacts like this?

Comment: This isn't enough context to determine what you're trying to achieve or what the problem is. Please share a [mcve] of your code and the page you're automating. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full code. `page.goto` should return a promise just fine, and you can easily run in parallel with some *independent* operations, but the `page` object itself needs to be synchronised - you cannot go to multiple urls at the same time in the same browser tab; all operations on the *same* `page` must be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error comes from the fact that you're using the same `page` object.

The following should work:

```js
const currentPage = browser.pages().then(allPages => allPages[0]);
const anotherPage = await browser.newPage();
const bothPages = [currentPage, anotherPage];
await Promise.all(
    bothPages.map(page => page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com"))
);
```